# Transaction has been reverted by the EVM - web3 error

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I have an issue when trying to deploy a smart contract with web3 from a `handleClick` function.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0x5deeb052b68c675d71db1fbe7a5cdcfb4ba5e099cbf21e1c666f306cfc8e1f58",
  "blockNumber": 10176288,
  "contractAddress": "0xBBc84ABa240653B95FF727f92639E2526C24Fcbd",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 5909534,
  "from": "0x4498f943e0a13d70b28e7565cf4e33bf443e6bf9",
  "gasUsed": 139864,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": null,
  "transactionHash": "0x1f040610e9165de4fc9ddba259ce5fc6d7e21becd395d40e90f807aa549511f2",
  "transactionIndex": 21,
  "type": "0x0"
}
```

My Code:

```
  const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
    const web3 = new Web3(
      "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/<private-id>"
    );
    const account1 = "<my-metamask-account-on-ropsten-with-eth>";
    const privateKey1 = Buffer.from(
        '<private-key>',
        'hex',
      )

    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err, txCount) => {
        //Smart contract data
        const contractData = '0x60806040523480156200001157600080fd.....very long'
      // create transaction
    const txParams = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(2000000),// Raise this if needed
        //to: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        data: contractData,
      }
      // The second parameter is not necessary if these values are used
      // sign the transaction
      const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams, { chain: 'ropsten', hardfork: 'petersburg' })
       tx.sign(privateKey1);
  
      const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
      const raw = '0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex')
      
      //broadcast transaction
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err, txHash) => {
        console.log('err', err, 'txHash', txHash)
      })
    });
  }
```

When I add a `to:x000000000000000000000000000` under "gas limit", the tx is a success, but it's not creating a contract.

The Smart contract from Remix:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestToken is ERC20 {
    constructor() ERC20("WER Token", "WER") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 5000000000000000000000000);
    }

    function decimals() public view virtual override returns (uint8) {
        return 18;
    }
}
```

From `truffle.config`:

```
ropsten: {
  // provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${infuraApiKey}`),
  network_id: 3, // Ropsten's id
  gas: 5500000, // Ropsten has a lower block limit than mainnet
  // confirmations: 2,    // # of confs to wait between deployments. (default: 0)
  // timeoutBlocks: 200,
  networkCheckTimeout: 99999, // # of blocks before a deployment times out  (minimum/default: 50)
  // skipDryRun: true     // Skip dry run before migrations? (default: false for public nets )
},
```